# Unity: public InputField variable does not accept Input Field objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to drag an *Input Field object* from Unity Hierarchy and store it inside a *public InputField variable*. However, while when I drag it, it shows that the object is indeed allowed to be stored, if I release the Input Field object, it does not get stored. and the variable is still showing *"None (Input Field)*. Also, when I try to press the circle (the one in the red square) to see the list of available Input Field objects, the list is empty, which is impossible, as it remains empty no matter how many input fields I create.

[image]

The Input Field object contains an Input Field component so it indeed counts as Input Field but I cannot figure out any way to solve this.

Comment: Did you maybe create a different class called "InputField"? Maybe trying to specify the exact namespace might help? `UnityEngine.UI.InputField ChatBox`?

Comment: @Kokosbrood thank you, this fixed it. I never thought there could be a different InputField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a wrong class InputField (don't know what or how) was used in the script so as suggested from @Kokosbrood, I used the whole path to the class `UnityEngine.UI.InputField`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
In UI there is a page called "Legacy"
and choose to apply the input field
It solved the problem for me.